# Proper Syntax for RegEx in Apache Directive Containers

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

1. What is the proper syntax to use RegEx with <Directory> and <DirectoryMatch> container paths? I'm just confused about the usage of ~ and ^. When and how should they be used?

```
<Directory ~ /home/user/(site|sitedev)>
    ...
</Directory>
<DirectoryMatch ^/home/user/(site|sitedev)>
    ...
</DirectoryMatch>
```

2. Are quotes always required or only when there's a space or special character in the value?

```
"/home/user/(site|sitedev)"
/home/user/(site|sitedev)
```

3. Also, what would be a RegEx to match all of the following folders:

```
/home/my/site
/home/my/siteblog
/home/my/sitestore
or any other that starts with /home/my/site doesn't go deeper like /home/my/siteblog/random
```

Can these two be a solution and what is the difference?

```
^/home/my/site.*
/home/my/^site.*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a specialist but I would say:

1. `<Directory ~ "^/home/user/(site|sitedev)">`
   is equivalent to
   `<DirectoryMatch "^/home/user/(site|sitedev)">`
   Both are core built-in. I prefer the second one as it's much
   clearer to read for a beginner.
2. You are right, quotes are required in case of spaces.
   I personally always quote them, for consistency in the config file.
3. `^/home/my/site.*` is the correct one:

   - `^` means "beginning with". This is why it can't be put before
     "sites" like you mentioned in `/home/my/^site.*`. If you don't
     put this `^` at the beginning, then an URL such as
     `/test/home/user/sitedev` would also match. This is because a
     pattern is used like a search and if it's found in the path then
     it matches, and you'll enter the `<DirectoryMatch>` block.

In opposite of `^`, you can use `$`, meaning "finishing with".
This is useful to match all JPEG files with `\.jpe?g$`, where
the dot should be escaped because `.` means "any character" and
`?` means that the "e" char before is optional. Of course, this example would not be used on a `<DirectoryMatch>` but on a
`<FilesMatch>`.

Caution, the regex can be case-sensitive or not, so it could not match
`/img/IMG234.JPG` depending on the config. I think this depends on
[RegexDefaultOptions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/mod/core.html#regexdefaultoptions).
If `ICASE` is "on" or not.

But I usually prefer solving this config question by enabling
the "case-insensitive" flag at the beginning of the pattern with
`(?i)\.jpe?g$` or enabling it for a specific part by wrapping it
between `(?i:` and `)` like this: `(?i:\.jpe?g)$`.

Examples:

- [case-insensitive flag at the beginning](https://regex101.com/r/1njIkb/1):
  `(?i)\.jpe?g$`
- [case-insensitive around a part of the pattern](https://regex101.com/r/1njIkb/2):
  `(?i:\.jpe?g)$`
- [case-insensitive around a part of the pattern, more complete example with a substitution](https://regex101.com/r/1njIkb/4):
  `/img/([^/]+)(?i:\.jpe?g)$`

  - `()` is used to capture a part of the path. Here it's the file
    basename. It will be available in a variable `$1` (1 = first group).
    If you have another capturing group, then you will have a second
    variable, called `$2`. See this [example with 2 capturing groups](https://regex101.com/r/1njIkb/6).
  - `[^ ]` means "not a char in the list". So `[^/]` means "any char
    which isn't a slash". The `*` means 0 or N times. But `+` means
    1 or N times. So `[^/]+` will match the basename of the file.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a few more dilemmas.

How to match the server root:
`<Directory>` or `<Directory /> <Directory "/">`

It is recommended for Apache performance to disable the .htaccess files everywhere except where needed, which are my WordPress sites in the sites and public_html folders. Can this be done like this:
`<Directory />
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory ~ ^/home/user/(sites|public_html)>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>`

Comment: @Kejatz Yes, scanning for *.htaccess* files takes some time. It seems you have access to the server configuration so you could move the content of the *.htaccess* file to the config of each dedicated virtual host. If you disable the override then don’t forget to search for all the *.htaccess* files which could be in sub-folders of your WordPress sites. After each update or module installation, you’ll have to check for changes in order to report them to your main virtual host configuration. But checking/setting HTTP headers for allowing content caching will have a higher performance impact.